# foreach loop syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

Consider myArray as an array of objects.

Are these two pieces of code equivalent ?

```
myArray.forEach((item) => {
  return doAnAction(item);
});


myArray.forEach((item) => {
      doAnAction(item);
    });
```

Is there any of them that is better in terms of syntax? If yes, why ?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent. `.forEach()` does not use the return value of it's callback. For more information, you can always check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It's a great resource.

Comment: They're syntactically identical but one of them has a pointless `return`. If you asking about code style then 1) opinion-based questions are off-topic on SO 2) Personally, I prefer the latter because adding `return` implies you're using the return value, which there is none.

Answer (score 3):

The better question is, why you do not use the function directly as callback, like

```
myArray.forEach(doAnAction);
```

The callback must follow the API of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which is

> Function to execute for each element, taking three arguments:
>
> - **currentValue**: The current element being processed in the array.
> - **index**: The index of the current element being processed in the array.
> - **array**: The array that `forEach()` is being applied to.

If you need only the element, then you could use the given callback directly without any mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand there's no difference between these two because you are providing an anonymous function to be applied to each element in the Array whereas the first one does return the result of `doAnAction(item)` (which is ignored anyway) and the second one does not.

So they are really equivalent, the second just makes more sense to me for the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to the `forEach` loop. It is just ES6 syntax.

With ES5, here is the right syntax:

```
myArray.forEach(function (item) {
  doAnAction(item);
});
```

With ES6, you have more possibilities:

```
// Solution #1
myArray.forEach((item) => {
  doAnAction(item);
});

// Solution #2
myArray.forEach(item => {
  doAnAction(item);
});

// Solution #3
myArray.forEach(item => doAnAction(item));
```

Comment: They weren't asking about syntax. They're asking about if the `return` changes this at all and, if so, how.

Comment: actually I was asking about the syntax :) its in the title of the post, clarified my post as well for other viewers! Thanks

Comment: @Rose Yeah, that is why I strictly answered about the syntax... ;) I do not know how your `doAnAction` function looks like, but be aware that it is generally awkward to use `return` in a `forEach` loop. It is much more frequent to use `return` with other core array methods like `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, `some`, `every`, etc.